# Spring Data Repository Multi-Threading Performance

Tags: java, mysql, spring, multithreading, performance

I am running into a performance issue with multiple threads accessing the same spring data repository object. Many of the threads are getting blocked while waiting on a lock for the repository object. Most all of the threads are performing the same query on the repository object. When this thread block runs, the CPU is maxed out on all cores. Occasionally it will dip, which I think is from the blocked threads waiting on a lock for the repository object. I have verified through profiling that multiple threads are waiting to call the same method in the repository object. I did see a boost in performance with changing the approach to use the method that returns a list. But the locking is still a bottleneck.

UPDATE: After more research, I have come to the conclusion that the repository object is a singleton. This one object is getting locked as each thread accesses it. How do I prototype the repository object? (I would create a read only repository for this use case.) Would the configuration have to change? Does Spring data already do this?

MWE:

```
public interface EntityJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<Entity, Integer> {
    @Query(value = "select * from SomeTable where id = (?1);", nativeQuery = true)
    Entity findById(int id);

    //Method that returns a list of Entities
    @Query(value = "select * from SomeTable where id in (?1);", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Entity> findAllWithIds(List<Integer> ids);
}

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class AThread implements Runnable {
    @Autowired
    EntityJpaRepository myRepository;

    final int someId;         

    public AThread(int someId) {
      this.someId = someId;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //may call subMethod 1
        myRepository.findById(someId);
        //may call subMethod 1
        List<Integer> ids = someMethodWhichReturnsIDs();
        myRepository.findAllWithIds(ids);
        //may call subMethod 1
    }

    public void subMethod1(){
        //sometimes loop
        subMethod2();
        //may call 
    }
    public void subMethod2(){
        //more stuff
        List<Integer> ids = someMethodWhichReturnsIDs();
        //more stuff
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = (ThreadPoolTaskExecutor) ctx.getBean("taskExecutor");

List<int> someInts;//assume this is full of ints.
for(int someId: someInts){
    taskExecutor.execute((Runnable)ctx.getBean("AThread", someId));
}
waitThreads(taskExecutor);
```

I will say I am getting a fair bit of performance out of what I currently have. I am  also not sure if I have setup my configuration correctly to be hitting the database with multiple threads/connections. I don't think this is the issue, but I have provided the full configuration. Any tips for performance are welcome.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages= {"org.repository"})
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:META-INF/spring/app-context.xml"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.somepackage")
public class JpaConfiguration {

    @Value("#{mainDataSource}")
    private javax.sql.DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> jpaProperties() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        props.put("hibernate.dialect", MySQLDialect.class.getName());
        props.put("hibernate.format_sql", true);
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
        return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager( entityManagerFactory().getObject());
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        lef.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
        lef.setJpaPropertyMap(this.jpaProperties());
        lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(this.jpaVendorAdapter());
        return lef;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor pool = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        pool.setCorePoolSize(100);
        pool.setMaxPoolSize(500);
        pool.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        pool.setKeepAliveSeconds(1800);
        return pool;
    }
}
```

Here is a stack trace of a thread when I pause the process/application while it is blocked. I also have sample output from the pro-filer. When it runs for a longer duration, the blocked time adds up. It is clearly getting blocked by another thread on the @Autowired repository object. I thought I have avoided this by using the prototype scope.

```
taskExecutor-1  BLOCKED 4.68003 6320    34  2062    1   java.lang.Object@5842edfa   taskExecutor-9


java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.isVisible(ClassUtils.java:1209)
org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.getAllInterfacesForClassAsSet(ClassUtils.java:1136)
org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.getAllInterfacesForClassAsSet(ClassUtils.java:1143)
org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.getAllInterfacesForClass(ClassUtils.java:1099)
org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:302)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy41.createNativeQuery(Unknown Source)
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.NativeJpaQuery.createJpaQuery(NativeJpaQuery.java:65)
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractStringBasedJpaQuery.doCreateQuery(AbstractStringBasedJpaQuery.java:72)
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.createQuery(AbstractJpaQuery.java:165)
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:197)
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:74)
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:98)
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:89)
org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:421)
org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:381)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:512)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(    CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:122)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy81.findAllWithIds(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor64.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy90.findAllWithIds(Unknown Source)
org.somepackage.AThread.subMethod2(AThread.java:696)
org.somepackage.AThread.subMethod1(AThread.java:346)
org.somepackage.AThread.run(AThread.java:132)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: How about getting the `EntityJpaRepository` in main (with `ctx.getBean`) and create your thread with `new AThread(theEntityJpaRepository)`. Also can't you use some method to fetch a `List<Entity>` instead?

Comment: I have used a list method to get some performance improvements. But the I still see the same behavior. Multiple threads are waiting to get into the repository method. I would like to think that the @Scope("prototype") annotation would give me a copy of the Repository object. I am starting to think that the @Autowired annotation is a shared (singleton) object.

Comment: Your code looks perfectly reasonable. It allows to perform up to 100 concurrent requests to the database. However i don't understand why your threads get blocked. Provided implementation of run method only performs single readonly request to the database and can't be blocked by other threads on isolation level lower than serializable. Can you please explain in more detail how "threads are getting blocked while waiting on a lock for the repository object" in real implementation of the run method?

Comment: How much RAM?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  What version of MySQL?  Provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE SomeTable`.

Comment: 32 GB RAM, MySQL 5.6.27, running locally spring application is running. This is a class project. The table is pretty simple:  CREATE TABLE someDB.`SOMETABLE`(id int not NULL ATUO_INCREMENT, stuff VARCHAR(45) Null, ...more stuff,..PRIMARY KEY(`id'), INDEX `indexOnID`..) Pretty simple table.

Answer (score 0):

This looks very much like a problem with loading the class of your query repeatedly.
Repeated loads of the same class can lead to heavy contention on the classloader lock. (example here: https://plumbr.eu/blog/locked-threads/classloading-and-locking )

The sharedEntityManager loads the class in line 302 - and this will run into the synchronized block on line 404 in the ClassLoader

Comment: The problem turned out to be my error. I had changed the priority of the program and still use the machine it was running on for other tasks. When I changed the priority of the task back to normal the problem went away. It was also not present when both the database process and the program in question were at the same priority.